# How can I compare changes against a GitHub project's first commit?

Tags: github, compare

On GitHub, you can [compare changes](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/) between two branches or tags by appending `/compare` to the repository path.

For example: let's say I wanted to view all commits for Notepad++ since the last major release. (Comparing *v7.4.2* against *HEAD*)

I take the project's repository URL, (https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/), and append [`compare/v7.4.2...HEAD`](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/compare/v7.4.2...HEAD).

While I can use HEAD to refer to the last commit in a project's history, I can't figure any way to reference the first commit in a project's history.

**Is it possible to compare a tag or commit against the first commit in a GitHub project's history?**

I've already tried [`compare/TAIL...v7.4.2`](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/compare/TAIL...v7.4.2), but that just leads to a page stating "*There isn’t anything to compare*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no symbolic ref like `HEAD` that references the first commit. One way to find the initial commit ID is to clone the repository and run `git log --reverse` or `git rev-list --format=%B --max-parents=0 HEAD`, which will list all commits accessible from `HEAD` with no parents. The initial commit will be included in that list. You can then use its ID to compare it to another commit or a tag on GitHub.

Here's an example with the `notepad-plus-plus` repository:

```
$ git log --oneline --reverse | head -n 1
ec7b0c2d v4.2 ready
```

[Comparing the initial commit with `v7.4.2` on GitHub](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/compare/ec7b0c2d...v7.4.2).

Comment: So basically, I need to find the specific hash for the original commit and compare it directly